# How to run application in detached state from windows command line

Tags: windows, command-line, process

I would like to start an application with command line under windows 7 or higher
I need this application PPID must be not the cmd.exe but higher level (explore.exe or other)

To make a try I simply wrote this batch file test.cmd :

```
echo "test"
start notepad
pause
```

And when I run the test.cmd on process explorer I have :

[image]

and I would like to have something like that :

[image]

I've try many things like

```
cmd /c notepad
```

or

```
start "" notepad
```

but never successfully

Any idea ?

Comment: `explorer c:\windows\notepad.exe` ?

Comment: That's works ! thanks. To mark the question as solved must I post an answer to my question ?